# How to add a scrollbar only from a div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let me first present my code sample:

```
<div id="StartScroll"></div>
    Many divs and content here !
<div id="EndScroll"></div>
```

My question is that how can i make a scroll bar which starts to scroll from div with id `StartScroll` and end scroling at div with id `EndScroll` .

Note that there is content before `StartScroll` and after `EndScroll` but i want the scroll bar should not be allow to go outside `StartScroll` and `EndScroll` .

How can i make this? Maybe with jQuery ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not wrap all this into one scrolled div?

Answer (score 0):

overflow-y: scroll could be the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/ds3nqbkz/2/

```
<div id="StartScroll" style="overflow-y: scroll">
Many divs and content here !<br />
Many divs and content here !<br />
Many divs and content here !<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content within the `startScroll` and `endScroll` division blocks within a `div` and assign the following style:

```
overflow-y: auto;
height: 200px; (or any specific height you wish to)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/p069kwyt/)

```
.makescroll {
height:150px
overflow-y:scroll;

}

<div class="makescroll">
<div id="StartScroll"></div>
<div id="EndScroll"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You then to wrap your content in single div and give it fixed height and make overflow-y : auto or scroll.

overflow-auto :- Will show scroll only if your content is more than height. Else it will be remove.
overflow-scroll :- Will always show scroll, in case content is less it will show disabled scroll.

You can use any of below approach to apply it. Examples have scroll you can change to auto if needed.

```
 #fixed{
 height:150px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 }

<div id="StartScroll"></div>
<div id="fixed">
// other content ere
</div>
<div id="EndScroll"></div>
</div>
```

#

```
<div id="StartScroll" inlineStyle="height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;"></div>
 <div id="fixed">
// other content ere
</div>
<div id="EndScroll"></div>
</div>
```

##############################################################################################

```
    fixedStyle{
 height:150px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}

<div id="StartScroll" class="fixedStyle"></div>
<div id="fixed">
// other content ere
</div>
<div id="EndScroll"></div>
 </div>
  ##################################################################################
  documentById("fixed").style = "height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;";

  <div id= "StartScroll"></div>
  <div id="fixed">
  // other content ere
  </div>
  <div id="EndScroll"></div>
   </div>
```